# error linking to boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost

when I try to link my c++ programme together with Intel MPI, I have this issue:

```
[key01027@ginar ising]$ mpiicc -o bin/ising obj/main.o obj/solver.o obj/periodicfunction.o obj/tools.o obj/treeofdevil.o  -L ~/ising_solver/gurobi650/linux64/lib/ -L ~/ising_solver/boost_install/lib/ -parallel -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi65 -lboost_regex -lboost_thread -lboost_system  -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization
obj/solver.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::iserializer<boost::mpi::packed_iarchive, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::load_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*, unsigned int) const':
solver.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost7archive6detail11iserializerINS_3mpi15packed_iarchiveESt6vectorIdSaIdEEE16load_object_dataERNS1_14basic_iarchiveEPvj[_ZNK5boost7archive6detail11iserializerINS_3mpi15packed_iarchiveESt6vectorIdSaIdEEE16load_object_dataERNS1_14basic_iarchiveEPvj]+0x209): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::array_wrapper<double> const boost::serialization::make_array<unsigned long>(double*, unsigned long)'
```

The key error is:

```
undefined reference to `boost::serialization::array_wrapper<double> const boost::serialization::make_array<unsigned long>(double*, unsigned long)'
```

I think i install boost mpi properly. I already include serialization in my linking (-lboost_serialization)... What should I do?

I am not sure it is because of the following serialization scheme, serializing boost tuple:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {


    template<typename Archive, typename T1>

    void serialize(Archive & ar,
                   boost::tuple<T1> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & t.get<0>();
    }

    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1,T2> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
    }


    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
    }


    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
    }

    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4,typename T5>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4, T5> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
        ar & t.get<4>();
    }

    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4,typename T5,typename T6 >
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4, T5, T6> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
        ar & t.get<4>();
        ar & t.get<5>();
    }


    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4,typename T5,typename T6 ,typename T7>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4, T5, T6 ,T7> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
        ar & t.get<4>();
        ar & t.get<5>();
        ar & t.get<6>();
    }


}}
```

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the error message, because according to the version 1.61.0 documentation the declaration of `make_array` is: `template<class T, class S> inline const array_wrapper<T> make_array(T* t, S s)`, so shouldn't the error message say `make_array<double, unsigned long>`?

Comment: the code itself is too huge... not sure if we could really debug anything out of it...

Comment: But it compiles and links in another machine and in my own machine though...

Comment: Maybe you have different boost versions? `array_wrapper` seems to be present only in the newest version 1.61.0 according to the online docs. Maybe you mixed up header and library versions? Anyway it would be helpful if you could verify the library versions on both machines. And for the code you could narrow it down to where you use boost::serialization in solver.cpp

Comment: ehm... the one in my mac is also 1.61.0 ... in solver.cpp, we have a lot of broadcasts..... maybe those that require serialization breaks for some mysterious reason?

Comment: Resolved.... install boost 1.58.0 instead and such problem shall not occur...

Comment: @VacassalAlsk Could you explain what the problem was? If this is a bug in 1.61.0 others might be interested in it. Or did you compile your object files with a different version than on the target?

Comment: Ehm... I would post an answer to this problem .... I am not sure the exact problem though.... I just walk around it....

Answer (score 1):

In the file "boost/include/boost/serialization/array.hpp", comment out these two lines:

```
template<class S>
friend const boost::serialization::array_wrapper<T> make_array( T* t, S s);
```

and it will link fine then.

Comment: Commenting out these two lines works but I'm not sure why it works. In fact, the developer didn't seem to know, either, as he/she left out a comment saying "I would like to make the copy constructor private but this breaks make_array.  So I try to make make_array a friend - but that doesn't build.  Need a C++ guru to explain this!" See [this file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/serialization/array.hpp).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... Basically, I re-perform the same installation as below with boost 1.58.0 instead of boost 1.61.0 :

[how do i install boost with intel compiler and intel mpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502034/how-do-i-install-boost-with-intel-compiler-and-intel-mpi)

The problem just goes away... I am not sure why....