# how do i install boost with intel compiler and intel mpi?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am following the instructions from:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-boost-with-intel-c-compiler-150

> Configuration Set Up and Bulld Process:
>
> Linux* and OS X*
>
> Run "source /bin/compilervars.sh {ia32 OR intel64}" or
>   "source /bin/compilervars.csh {ia32 OR intel64}" cd
>   /tools/build
>
> ./bootstrap.sh
>
> ./b2 install --prefix= Add /bin to your PATH
>
> cd
>
> For 32-bit: b2 --build-dir= toolset=intel
>   stage For 64-bit: b2 --build-dir=
>   address-model=64 toolset=intel stage
>
> For 64-bit: b2 --build-dir= address-model=64
>   toolset=intel stage

trying to install boost with intel compiler and intel mpi. However, it does not seem to generate the lib/ and  include/ for me to compile... Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

ok,.... additionally I realize that I need to do:

1, change project-config.jam , add one line : "using mpi : mpiicpc ; " at the end

2, then :  b2 --prefix=$myplace/boost_install/ --build-dir=$myplace/boost_install/ address-model=64 toolset=intel install